# how to retrieve data from a foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

been coding since morning and i cant get any data from the auth_user. i made a class in my model. here's the code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as DjangoUser
......
class Author(models.Model):
    """
    Data model that holds posts' authors as shown in author pages
    """
    django_user = models.ForeignKey(DjangoUser, primary_key=True)
    about = models.TextField('About', null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = ImageWithThumbsField('Pic', upload_to=settings.PATH_AVATAR, blank=True, null=True, sizes=settings.SIZES_AVATAR)
```

in my DjangoUser model, i want to get the first_name...

what will i code in my view file to retrieve the first name of the author?

thanks a lot. your answers i greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the [auth documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.first_name), the user model contains a `first_name` attribute.

```
# get the author from the database using a user as a primary key
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
author = Author.objects.get(user)

# display the author's first name by accessing the 
# User model first, then its properties
author.django_user.first_name
```

However, you should really read [Storing Additional Information About the User](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) in the same auth documentation page.  It explains the correct way to build a profile for the User object.  This way, the profile is stored *beside* the User, leaving the User object pristine.  This is by design since you can use the [get_profile()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile) method to dig into that profile.

Comment: this code: author = Author.objects.get(id=1); will get an error of: Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are: about, avatar, django_user; since in Author's class only have those field..

Comment: Thanks.  Code fixed.  Though the proper Django profiles route is the one I'd still recommend.